# php search URL extention from list of domains

Tags: php, regex

Hi i have a text file 'A' having a list of domains like this

```
example.com,
example.in,
example.co.in,
example.net,
example.org,
second.in,
second.co.in,
```

I need get list of  .co.in and .in and put them in other text file 'B' like this

```
example.in,
example.co.in,
second.in,
second.co.in,
```

can anyone help me out

Comment: So `b` should just have any domain with a U.S. TLD removed? Here's a starting point `/\.(com|net|org),$/m`.

Comment: no i need the match case from the different example domains

Comment: ends with .in and .co.in both

Comment: Okay, so ending in `.in` would be correct, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Pull content from file
$fileA = file_get_contents(PATH TO FILE A);

//explode into an array on the comma
$domainArray = explode(",", $fileA);

//Loop over the array and check for the ".in" extension
foreach($domainArray as $item)
{
    //If the '.in' extension is present at the end of the string, add it to a new string
    if(substr($item, -3) === '.in')
    {
        $newDomains .= $item;
    }
}

//Finally, dump the contents into a new file.
file_put_contents('NAME OF FILE', $newDomains);
```

Comment: i don't see any $newDomains in B.txt

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex:

```
/^(.*?\.in,)$/m
```

https://regex101.com/r/rC0bZ3/5

PHP Usage:

```
preg_match_all('/^(.*?\.in,)$/m', 'example.com,
example.in,
example.co.in,
example.net,
example.org,
second.in,
second.co.in,', $found);
print_r($found[1]);
```

With this approach `$found[1]` will have all `.in` domains as an array. You can use `file_get_contents` to populate the field the regex checks. Then `file_put_contents` to create/write to the `b.txt.`

Alternatively you could use the `file` function, http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php. With this approach you wouldn't need the `m` modifier and could write each line to `b.txt` as it encounters it.

Comment: I don't see any output  in $found but our regex is 100% correct